# Auto add a specific product to cart based on other cart items count in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, cart

I am trying to add a product called (Delivery Charge) to the cart based on how many products I have in the cart.

**Cart Example:**
Product A (QTY 5)
Product B (QTY 2)
Product C (QTY 4)
Delivery Charge (QTY 3) **This is 3 because that is the total line items it should be counting that was added to cart before the delivery charge product was added.

Having troubles with my code:

```
/* Function to get total Products (line items) not qty of each */
function count_item_in_cart() {
    global $woocommerce; 
    $counter = 0; 

    foreach ($woocommerce->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item) {
        $counter++;
    }
    return $counter;
}

/* Add DC (Delivery Charge Product) to Cart based on qty */ 
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'delivery_charge_add_product_to_cart' ); 
function delivery_charge_add_product_to_cart() {
    /* Establish Product Delivery Charge Product ID */
    global $woocommerce;
    $product_id = 4490;  /* Product ID to add to cart */
    $quantity = count_item_in_cart(); 

    if ($quantity > 0) {
        WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $product_id, $quantity); 
    }
}
```

It always returns a higher number. I think it is counting the QTY for each product and not actual product item.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code will auto add/update your additional product "Delivery charge" to cart each time a product is added to cart and  will handle all possible cases:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'add_delivery_charge_to_cart', 10, 1 );
function add_delivery_charge_to_cart( $cart ) {
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    if ( did_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals' ) >= 2 )
        return;

    $dcharge_id  = 4490; // Product Id "Delivery charge" to be added to cart
    $items_count = 0;  // Initializing

    // Loop through cart items
    foreach ( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
        // Check if "Delivery charge" product is already in cart
        if( $cart_item['data']->get_id() == $dcharge_id ) {
            $dcharge_key = $cart_item_key;
            $dcharge_qty = $cart_item['quantity'];
        }
        // Counting other items than "Delivery charge"
        else {
            $items_count++;
        }
    }

    // If product "Delivery charge" is in cart, we check the quantity to update it if needed
    if ( isset($dcharge_key) && $dcharge_qty != $items_count ) {
        $cart->set_quantity( $dcharge_key, $items_count );
    }
    // If product "Delivery charge" is not in cart, we add it
    elseif ( ! isset($dcharge_key) && $items_count > 0 ) {
        $cart->add_to_cart( $dcharge_id, $items_count );
    }
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: Great! I will try this and get back to you!

Comment: Do you know how I could add the delivery charge "on submit" of "Checkout" page only so that it is not visible to the user? Only shown as a line item after they click checkout and are redirected to the thank you page? So it still gets added to the cart but not until they click the last checkout button?

Comment: As your delivery charge is a product that is related to add-to-cart event and as it's a cart item itself, I don't see any way to make what you should like. There is many other ways to add a delivery charge and you will have to explore those other ways which can be related to [`woocommerce_package_rates` hook](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A3730754+woocommerce_package_rates) or to [`woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees` hook](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A3730754+woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees), so not using a product as a delivery charge.

Comment: Ok Thank you again! A huge help!

Comment: There is one issue I ran into with the way we add the delivery charge to the cart per product. When on the cart page, if someone deletes an item, it is not updating the delivery charge qty. Would you have a code that can delete the item if an item is deleted from cart? Any help would be deeply appreciated!